Chrome extension with slate.js is not working. Content script is not UTF-8 encoded
I'm building a chrome extension using wxt framework (https://wxt.dev/) using React+Typescript.
I want to use a wysiwyg text editor, and I decided to go with slate. Now as soon as I render the <Editable /> component from slate (following their official doc example from here - https://docs.slatejs.org/walkthroughs/01-installing-slate), I get this error -
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not load file 'content-scripts/content.js' for content script. It isn't UTF-8 encoded.
I believe this is some issue with Slate.js + wxt but I'm not entirely sure. Unable to wrap my head around this.
// File: content.tsx
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./content/App.tsx";
import "./content/content.css";

export default defineContentScript({
  matches: ["<all_urls>"],
  cssInjectionMode: "ui",

  async main(ctx) {
    const ui = await createShadowRootUi(ctx, {
      name: "example-ui",
      position: "inline",
      onMount: (container) => {
        const app = document.createElement("div");
        container.append(app);

        const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(app);
        root.render(<App />);
        return root;
      },
      onRemove: (root) => {
        root?.unmount();
      },
    });

    ui.mount();
  },
});


// File: content/App.tsx
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import "./App.css";
import { Slate, withReact } from 'slate-react';
import {createEditor } from 'slate';
import ActionBar from './ActionBar';


const App: React.FC = () => {
    const [actionBarActive, setActionBarActive] = React.useState(false);
    const [selectedText, setSelectedText] = React.useState<string>("");
    const [url, setUrl] = React.useState<string>("");

    const [editor] = useState(() => withReact(createEditor()));

    browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse: (args:any) => void) => {
        if (message.action === "toggleActionBar") {
            console.log("Toggle action bar");
            setActionBarActive(!actionBarActive);
            setSelectedText(message.data.selectedText[0].result);
            setUrl(message.data.url);
        }
        return true;
    })

    return (
        <Slate editor={editor} initialValue={[]}>
            <ActionBar selectedText={selectedText} url={url} actionBarActive={actionBarActive} setActionBarActive={setActionBarActive} />
        </Slate>
    );
};

export default App;

// File: content/ActionBar.tsx


import React, { useState } from 'react';
import "./App.css";
import { Editable, withReact } from 'slate-react';
import { createEditor } from 'slate';

const parseUrl = (url: string) => {
    const postUrlRaw = new URL(url);
      let hostName = postUrlRaw.hostname;
      if ("www." === hostName.substring(0, 4)) {
        hostName = hostName.substring(4);
      }
      return hostName;
}

interface ActionBarProps {
    selectedText: string;
    url: string;
    actionBarActive: boolean;
    setActionBarActive:React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>
}

const ActionBar: React.FC<ActionBarProps> = ({url, selectedText, actionBarActive, setActionBarActive}) => {
    const [editor] = useState(() => withReact(createEditor()));
    return (
        <>
        {actionBarActive && <div className='app-container' onClick={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            if(e.target === e.currentTarget) {
                setActionBarActive(false);
            }
        }}>
            <div className='action-bar-container'>
                <div className='action-bar'>
                    {selectedText.trim().length > 0 && <div className='selected-text-container'><pre>{selectedText}</pre></div>}
                    <p>{parseUrl(url)}</p>
                    <Editable />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>}
        </>
    );
};

export default ActionBar;

Edit: The issue doesn't appear as soon as I remove the <Editable /> component from ActionBar.tsx
I'm unable to wrap my head around the issue. Since wxt uses babel to compile js, I've tried manually setting compile options there but that didn't seem to work.
